# Parse throwing NullPointerException for logInInBackground

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, gradle

I have a login method like:

```
private void login() {
    String username = this.email.getText().toString();
    String password = this.password.getText().toString();

    ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (user != null) {
                // Successful login. Redirect to the main screen.
                startActivity(mainView);
            } else {
                // We failed. Notify the user and log.
                message.setText("Error logging in. Please try again later.");
                Log.e("Error", "Error logging in user", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It looks fine,however, when I attempt to log in, I get a `NullPointerException` stating:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.parse.ParseHttpClient com.parse.ParsePlugins.restClient()' on a null object reference
```

Now, at first, I blamed Parse, but I am wondering if I am missing something. Parse has been added to my Gradle dependencies via:

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'
```

Am I declaring my dependencies wrong? Is this a bug in parse, or am I just using the method incorrectly.

Comment: I can't see where you are invoking `restClient`.

Comment: did you call `Parse.initialize` ?

Comment: in my Application  class.

Comment: post your full stacktrace

Comment: What line causes the NPE?

Answer (score 3):

Did you change the application in your manifest?

Remember it when you made all this stuff

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".android.ParseApplication"
```

is really important! i just forget it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you initialize parse from within your OnCreate() Method

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "AppID", "ClientID");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and I solved it. Probably you are missing one of these two points:

1. You have to create a class that extends `Application`, and add there `Parse.Initialize(..)`, as explained [here](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing)
2. Don't forget to declare this class in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

Answer (score 0):

If you are using parse opensource server and you have this problem, then this will help you.

I was initializing my parse like this:

```
                Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(MainApplication.this)
                    .applicationId("my_super_secret_id")
                    .clientKey(null)
                    .server("https://mysupersecretpage.com/parse/").build();
```

So what fixed the problem is putting .clientKey("")

This is a workaround, but looks like there is a bug in sdk.